# powerbi reports without asking for credentials

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, powerbi

How to call Power BI reports from ASP.NET C# web application by passing the credentials. **Please note that we are not using Azure AD**.
We have provided the view permission in the workspace for some users in Power BI Service.
We want to call the Power BI reports without asking SignIn page.
please provide the solution to control the SignIn page if user call the Power BI reports from web application

Comment: Do you want to use Guests? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-azure-ad-b2b

Answer (score 0):

Use Power BI Embedding for this.  Your users will authenticate to your application, which will use a Service Principal to authenticate to Power BI and authorize the embedding.

Follow the tutorial here: [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content using a sample embed for your customers' application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core)